# How to get the number of subgraphs to a 4-vertice complete graph?

Tags: graph-theory

I have this complete graph with 4 vertices and I want to calculate the total number of subgraphs.
[image]

If we start in order going from 0 and up. There is 1 way to select 0 vertices so +1. And the case with 1 vertex, there is 4 ways to choose from the 4 vertices so +4. The case with 2 vertices would add 6 subgraphs since there are 6 edges so +6. So we now have 11 subgraphs. Is my start correct, and how do I continue while making sure that I don't forget any possible subgraph? I have looked at other posts on math stackexchange about these sort of problems but I don't understand them. Please help.

Comment: Are you considering labelled subgraphs or unlabelled subgraphs? i.e. is the graph with only $1$ and $2$ connected considered the same as the graph where only $3$ and $4$ are connected. If you are considering labelled subgraphs the question is much easier to answer.

Comment: Upon looking at your working it appears that you are considering labelled induced subgraphs, is that correct? If so then the method you are using would work, however it might be a little slow. One alternative method would be as follows. You would have $2^4$ (induced) subgraphs as each (induced) subgraph corresponds to a particular set of vertices, and so by considering the powerset of the set of vertices we can conclude there are $2^4$  (induced) subgraphs.

Comment: @Fishbane I'm not really sure what that means. Can you link to some explanation of that so I can read it and then answer your question?

Comment: Most courses on graph theory would explain what this means. It would probably be easier if you said where you encountered this problem and what your current understanding of graphs is.

Comment: The problem just states (translated): Calculate the number of subgraphs to the complete graph with the vertex set {1, 2, 3, 4} . So I made the graph, which should be correct and tried to solve it.

Comment: How does your course (I shall assume you are on a course given the way you are phrasing things) define a subgraph. I ask particularly because you appear to be translating from another language, so conventions may differ on what terms mean (or otherwise you might be improperly translating the mathematical terms).

Comment: Yes I'm translating from another language to the best of my ability. The definition of a subgraph states: A subgraph to a graph G is a graph G' that is made up of a subset of G:s nodes and edges. If G = (V, E) and G' = (V', E') then V' is a subset of V and E' is a subset of E

Comment: Okay. Given this definition the method you were using won't work because you are excluding certain types of subgraphs, namely ones which are missing some edges. However because we are dealing with a complete graph things are somewhat easier than they could be. To give an explicit method of constructing all subgraphs we can start how you did by choosing all possible sets of vertices of a certain size, then for each edge we can either include it or exclude it. However there will be a fairly large number of subgraphs so it would be a good idea to only cont the options. ...

Comment: To do that we can use the fact that there is lots of symmetry involved. Specifically for any particular number of vertices we can calculate the number of edges between them by counting the number of possible pairs $n$ (for example for $3$ vertices there are $3$ possible pairs so $n=3$), the because each edge can either be kept or removed we get $2^n$ possible subgraphs for a particular number of vertices. Then we can multiply that by the number of ways to choose that many vertices, and then sum those values for each possible number of vertices. Sorry for the bad explaination.

Answer (score 1):

As @Fishbane correctly pointed out, if we consider only the induced subgraphs of a complete graph, then there are exactly as many subsets of the set of $n=|V(G)|$ elements, that is
$$
\sum_{k=0}^n\binom{n}{k}=2^n.
$$

If we need to count the number of all subgraphs, then we need a refinement. For a given subset $S\subset V(G)$, $|S|=k$, there are exactly as many subgraphs $H$ for which $V(H)=S$ as there are subsets in the set of complete graph edges on $k$ vertices, that is $2^{\binom{k}{2}}$.

It follows that the total number of subgraphs of the complete graph on $n$ vertices can be calculated by the formula
$$
\sum_{k=0}^n2^\binom{k}{2}\binom{n}{k}.
$$

**Note.**
I mistakenly deleted my previous answer. I am restoring it by correcting a typo in the last formula. Thanks @jjagmath for pointing me to that typo.